# Avoid Specific exceptions in java

Tags: java, exception

I have a code like this.

```
try {
        st = Session.getDbConnection().createStatement();
        delSt = Session.getDbConnection().createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT msg_id,message,mobile_no FROM sms");

        while (rs.next()) {   
            delSt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM sms WHERE msg_id = '" + rs.getString(1) + "'");

            System.out.println("Message sent");
        }
        Session.getDbConnection().commit();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex.getMessage().startsWith("error occurred at recursive")){
        }
        else{
            logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (delSt != null) {
                delSt.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            logger.error(ex1.getMessage(), ex1);
            ex1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            if (!Session.getDbConnection().isClosed()) {
                Session.getDbConnection().close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex1) {
            logger.error("ERROR:Closing Database Connection:" + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

    } finally {
    }
```

Now In this case I want to ignore/avoid the exception "error occurred at recursive SQL level 1" for log. But I want to log other than this exception. What's wrong with my code.
Thanks

Comment: `avoiding` is different than `ignoring`!

Comment: I don't know. What *is* wrong ? Exceptions etc.?

Comment: Now that's an ugly example of using `if`. Instead of `if (condition) {} else { doSomething(); }` do `if (!condition) { doSomething(); }` just for the sake of readability. But that's just a sidenote.

Comment: isn't working means, it's still keeping the exception log "error occurred at recursive"

Answer (score 2):

I don't think

```
 if (ex.getMessage().startsWith("error occurred at recursive")){
 }
```

is particularly safe. You're assuming the exception message is never null (!) and then performing a comparison on the exception message. I would rather catch specific classes of exception e.g.

```
   catch (SQLException e)
```

and filter on the class itself. You can also make use of the error codes returned by the database. These are database-vendor specific, note. See [SQLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) doc for more details and in particular the `getErrorCode()` method (I'm assuming you're actually catching `SQLExceptions` here, but the principle is wider)

Other comments. You should be closing the resultset/statements/connection outside the exception handling and in your `finally` block. You need to free those resources *regardless* of exceptions/success. Perhaps check out [DBUtils.closeQuietly()](http://j2eedev.org/use-apache-dbutils-jar-to-ease-closing-jdbc-resources-in-application/) to do this safely and concisely.